# Kafka stream how to test a sliding window?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, streaming, apache-kafka-streams

I have a test that test a sliding window like this :

```
.groupByKey
.windowedBy {
        TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
          .advanceBy(Duration.ofMinutes(1)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(0))
      }
      .aggregate(...)
      .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded()))
```

I need to test that the sliding window produce the right output after a step.
I did something like this :

```
for (i <- 0 to 8) testDriver.pipeInput(record..., T0 to T8)// produce one record every minute (9 records)

for (i <- 0 to 8)testDriver.pipeInput(record..., T8 + 5min) // these comes with a timestamp > 10 minutes tso there are on a second window
```

The first loop should produce a result within the first timewindow, and after the sliding of 1 minutes the second loop should produce a second record with the resulut of the second window (after sliding)
How can I check that ? I don't understand exactly how to use the outputs readers to check these two results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would call `testDriver.readOutput()` whenever you expect that the output is available. Of course, you would need to write the result into an output topic, e.g.,

```java
...
.suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded()))
.toStream()
.to("output-topic");
```

Comment: if I send a record every minutes during 10 minutes and I have a hopping window and an aggregation that produce one result like I wrote in my question (10 min with a step of 1 minute). I would expect 10 output, right ?

Comment: Sounds about right to me (assuming that each record has the same key).